Why spring is not able to get the beans when I have given @ComponentScan?
I am trying to understand this question, suppose I am having spring without spring boot, I am creating a new context but without passing the configuration class like below
@ComponentScan("com.main.config")
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()){
        MyBean mybean = context.getBean(MyBean.class);
        System.out.println(mybean.getMessage());
    }

}} 

Since i have given @ComponentScan and the package where my configuration class is present with the @Configuration why it's not able to find the configuration class?, why should i need to pass my configuration class in the constructor for it find the class like this
  try(var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ProjectConfig.class))

After adding the configuration class as parameter in the constructor it works fine but when i dont even though i have the @ComponentScan it is not working and throwing error as
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4c70fda8 has not been refreshed yet
why the context needs to be refreshed?. Why the @ComponentScan doesn't work here.

Please read a tutorial about how to start a SpringBoot application. A simple main is not enough.

@f1sh suppose I am having spring without spring boot

@f1sh as I mentioned my question is when using only spring without spring boot. I understand spring boot does all these things behind.

Why do you think the @ComponentScan in your first snippet should do something?

This is how AnnotationConfigApplicationContext is designed. If no component classes are provided we have to register them manually, then refresh the context. See new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext() constructor's javadoc

Create a new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext that needs to be populated through register calls and then manually refreshed.

@ComponentScan("com.main.config")
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()){
        context.register(Application.class);
        context.refresh();
        MyBean mybean = context.getBean(MyBean.class);
        System.out.println(mybean.getMessage());
    }
}}

Or use your Application class as configuration file
@ComponentScan("com.main.config")
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class)){
        MyBean mybean = context.getBean(MyBean.class);
        System.out.println(mybean.getMessage());
    }
}}

